# Android - How to parse JSONObject and JSONArrays from api.rottentomatoes

Tags: java, android, json

so, there's this JSON code. Im trying to get the "abridged_cast".
but its complicated.
its JSONObject
inside JSONArray onside jSONObject Inside JsonArray....

```
{
    "total": 591,
    "movies": [
        {
            "title": "Jack and Jill",
            "year": 2011,
            "runtime": "",
            "release_dates": {
                "theater": "2011-11-11"
            },
            "ratings": {
                "critics_score": -1,
                "audience_score": 90
            },
            "synopsis": "",
            "posters": {
                "thumbnail": "",
                "profile": "",
                "detailed": "",
                "original": ""
            },
            "abridged_cast": [
                {
                    "name": "Al Pacino",
                    "characters": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Adam Sandler",
                    "characters": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Katie Holmes",
                    "characters": []
                }
            ],
            "links": {
                "self": "",
                "alternate": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "self": "",
        "next": ""
    },
    "link_template": ""
}
```

this is my code for getting "title" and "year"

```
if (response != null) {
            try {
                // convert the String response to a JSON object,
                // because JSON is the response format Rotten Tomatoes uses
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                // fetch the array of movies in the response
                JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                // add each movie's title to an array
                movieTitles = new String[movies.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                    movieTitles[i] = movie.getString("title");
                }
```

hope someone would help me because i cant figure out how to get the abridged_cast"

Comment: The same way you got the title, except it's an array just like `movies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movies` contains an array of "movie" objects. Each one of those objects contains a field `abridged_cast` that is an array of (let's call them "cast member") objects.

If you're not going to map to a POJO and instead are going through the JSON, you simply need to get that array in your loop after getting `movie`, and get each "cast member" object from that array in the same manner using another loop.

```
...
JSONArray cast = movie.getJSONArray("abridged_cast");
for (int j = 0; j < cast.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject castMember = cast.getJSONObject(j);
    ... 
}
```

**Edit from comments:** Your original question involved how to extract the information from the JSON you have; the above code explains that. It now seems like you're asking a more fundamental programming question around how to use it.

If you're going to use the included `org.json` classes that come with Android, you now know how to access the information in the returned JSON object. And you could write methods around the parsed `JSONObject` to access the data as-is using the objects and methods from the `json.org` package. For example, you could write a "getMovie()" method that took the name of the movie as a string and searched that "movies" array for the right one and returned it as a `JSONObject`.

Normally you would create classes in Java that encapsulate the data returned in that JSON and use data structures that lend themselves to your access patterns (For example, a `Map` that conatained all the movies using their names as keys). Using the `org.json` classes you'll have to instantiate those objects and populate them manually as you parse the JSON like you're doing in your question. If you used either the `Gson` or `Jackson` JSON parsing libraries they are capable of taking the JSON you have and mapping all the data to the classes  your create and returning them in a single call.

Comment: there's a problem with your method... the movie castMember are been save as one big array and every time i press a movie from a list it just give me the name of one actor... how do i save from each movie the actors as an array for just the specific movie and not for all the movies?

Comment: @user2252496 - you'd ... want a data structure that encapsulated that information and allowed you to access it; a `Map` for example. Ideally you'd create an actual object (class) in Java that basically mirrored the "movie" object you have in that JSON array which is the normal way to approach these things.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
                 String Movie = null;
                 String abridged = null;
                JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                 for (int i = 0; i< jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                        Movie     =   jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("movies").toString();
                        System.out.println("movies="+Movie);
                       abridged =   jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("abridged_cast").toString();
                 }


                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(Movie);
                 for (int i = 0; i< jArray.length(); i++) {
                     String title       =   jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title").toString();
                     System.out.println("title="+title);

                 }

                JSONArray jabridgeArray = new JSONArray(abridged);
                 for (int i = 0; i< jabridgeArray.length(); i++) {
                     String title       =   jabridgeArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString();
                     System.out.println("title="+title);

                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Because you don't answer his question? In fact, all you did was break his already working code.

Comment: ::sigh::. His existing code works. **Read his question**. And there's no need to run your code since not only doesn't it work, it still wouldn't answer his question if it did.